# How do I connect io.Reader and io.Writer?

Tags: go, io

I'm writing a long running task which fetch from mongodb (using mgo) multiple times. Then write it to an xlsx file using [this module](https://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx#File.Save). Then read it again using `os.Open` then store it to my ftp server.

`Stor` function consume my memory so much, So I think there should be a way not to save file but pass my data from xlsx.Write to ftp.Store directly. (If I can stream simultaneously would be perfect because I don't have to hold all of my documents in server's memory before send them to Stor function)

These are prototype of the functions

`func (f *File) Write(writer io.Writer) (err error)` [xlsl](https://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx#File.Write)

`func (ftp *FTP) Stor(path string, r io.Reader) (err error)` [ftp](https://godoc.org/github.com/dutchcoders/goftp)

Comment: For people coming here to simply read from a `io.Reader` and write its contents to a `io.Writer`, use `io.Copy(w, r)`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to use [io.Pipe](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe). You can do:

```
reader, writer := io.Pipe()
errChan := make(chan error)
go func() {
    errChan <- myFTP.Stor(path, reader)
}()
err := myXLS.Write(writer)
// handle err
err = <-errChan
// handle err
```

You might want to `writer.CloseWithError(err)` if `xlsx.Write` returns an error without closing the writer.

Comment: io.Pipe() does not return io.Writer and io.Reader but it returns *PipeReader, *PipeWriter instead. Are they the same?

Comment: @MethuzKaewsai-kao: [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is an interface, `*PipeReader` is a concrete type which implements the `io.Reader` interface. (Same goes for the writers.) So yes, you can use a `*PipeReader` in any place which accepts an `io.Reader`.

Comment: Do note that io.[Pipe() creates a synchronous in-memory pipe](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Pipe). This means that there is a limit on how much you can write depending on how you read from the reader end. E.g. if using bytes.Buffer.ReadFrom() with the reader, this limits the amount to be written. (In my case to 64 kb, but may potentially vary depending on architecture and go version)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `bytes.Buffer`:

```
func uploadFileToQiniu(file *xlsx.File) (key string, err error) {
    key = fmt.Sprintf("%s.xlsx", util.SerialNumber())
    log.Debugf("file key is %s", key)

    log.Debug("start to write file to a writer")
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err = file.Write(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error caught when writing file: %v", err)
        return
    }

    size := int64(buf.Len())
    log.Debugf("file size is %d", size)
    err = Put(key, size, buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error caught when uploading file: %v", err)
    }
    return key, nil
}
```

```
func Put(key string, size int64, reader io.Reader) error {}
```